# Custom jQuery Delayed Callback

Tags: jquery, callback, delay

I am playing with extending jQuery with a function that has two params: a callback function and a timeout. I'm on pre 1.4 so I don't have the .delay() built-in, but even that isn't really what I want.

I've started out with the below, but am unclear as to

1 why is the callback function undefined inside the setTimeout, and

2 how *should* I be calling it, if possible?

```
$.extend({
  delay: function(callback, msec) {

    alert(callback);     // as expected
    alert(msec);         // as expected

    if(typeof callback == 'function'){

      setTimeout("callback()", msec); // why callback() undefined here?!

    }

  }

});

//Usage:
$.delay(function(){
  alert("this is delayed 5sec");
}, 5000);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

callback is undefined because you're passing it as a string. do this:

```
setTimeout(callback, msec);
```

Answer (score 2):

@Jason already said how to call the callback correctly.

> why is the callback function undefined inside the setTimeout?

When `"callback()"` is evaluated, the function where you called `setTimeout` (`delay`) is finished. The string is evaluated in the global scope where the function `callback` does not exist (and I think it will *always* be evaluated in the global scope).

Example:

```
function a() {
    alert('a');
}

(function() {
    function a() {
        alert('b');
    }
    setTimeout('a()', 1000);
})();
```

will alert `a`.

---

Whereas if you create a closure and evaluate `a()` inside an anonymous function, it will alert `b`:

```
function a() {
    alert('a');
}

(function() {
    function a() {
        alert('b');
    }
    setTimeout(function() {eval('a()');}, 1000);
})();
```